# Other than DSL what is the utility of Cucumber over TestNG and Junit and how to use @Test annotations with Gherkin's Given When Then annotation?

Tags: selenium, cucumber, testng

I've 2 questions.

1. I know Domain Specific Language could be used to write acceptance cases in cucumber but while implementing those steps @Given, @When ,@Then annotations are used in step definition then if one doesn't have to use dataprovider or grouping or parallel execution and run it using IDE then does TestNg or Junit would be required?
2. As @Test is generally used for a complete test scenario when only TestNg is used so when Cucumber is also used then is there a need to use @Test annotation if yes then how can it be used along with @Given, @When, @Then?

Comment: Depending on who contributes to the tests, cucumber is meant to approach testing with [TDD/BDD](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/15263/exactly-how-are-bdd-tdd-atdd-kanban-and-scrum-different-from-a-waterfall-appr) in mind. See [Agile](http://www.jamesshore.com/Agile-Book/) for more details on why you might want to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ad 1.
The upside of using Gherkin is to have specifications that can also be read by non-programmers.
The upside of using Gherkin with Cucumber is that you can automate these specifications to have automated tests, or executable specifications.
Another upside of automating with Cucumber, is that steps are implemented to be reused which makes it easier to add similar test scenarios. (This reusability of steps is not the case with unit test tools, although one might argue they're easier to write anyway.)
The downside of having to implement the step definitions is having to implement the step definitions, which can take some time. And some developers consider this to be overly verbose. So I'd only do it if it brings added value in communicating with non-technical people.

Note 1: You will still need JUnit (or TestNg) as an assertion library.

Note 2: Cucumber by itself does not support parallel execution.

Ad 2. 
You will not need to use @Test annotation with Cucumber